# Can all CFT state be prepared through scale invariant MERA

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, conformal-field-theory, quantum-computer, holographic-principle

It is known that in numeric computation, scale invariant MERA is useful for representing a CFT vacuum state. Is the converse true? i.e. all CFT vacuum state (the quantum state with translation and scaling symmetry) can be represented as scale invariant MERA with type (1,2) isometries and type (2,2) disentangler?